# Debug sessions ending unexpectedly in visual studio when web browser is resized

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, google-chrome

This has been an issue for me since a few updates ago.
I was hoping it'd be fixed by now, but it has not.

I am currently running the latest version: 15.7.2

I am using verison  66.0.3359.181 of chrome

I am using core 2 MVC ASP.NET, with the .NET framework.

---

***The issue is as follows:***

**I click to run the program as normal**.

**Chrome opens up**.

Important to note here is that -before- I was having this issue, visual studio would open a separate instance of chrome that didn't have any of my extensions, and could not have it's tabs merged with my other Chrome Windows. This was extremely useful functionality because it meant I didn't have to worry about the extentions affecting anything, however since the update its' been lost.

**All appears to be fine, the app is there in the chrome window.** HOWEVER when I try to resize the window (which I often do) or make the window fullscreen (either by bashing it against the top of the screen, or hitting the maximize button) the window suddently closes, and I'm back in Visual Studio, the debug session has ended.

**This behaviour is as though I'm closing the window with the close button.**

I am at a loss for what to do, and this problem is extremely fustrating to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: search for chrome in tools options and uncheck both, I have this same issue 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't fixed this, but came up with a work around.

Adrian's comment made me go and check the debug options for Chrome. However he said to uncheck both. However when I got there, I noticed they were already both un-ticked.

So I ticked javascript debugging, and this made it go back to the old behavior of opening up a chrome window that doesn't have any extensions. This window, if I resize it, doesn't affect my debug session.

I have, however submitted a bug report to MS to see if they can fix the problem properly.